# C++ - How to make 4x4 matrix and cout columns from top to the bottom (need to decryption a string)

Tags: c++, arrays, matrix

I am a begginner in C++ and I just started working out with matrices that are not simple. I found out about "Caesar Cipher" algorithm or whatever it is called and I made some task for me to do. I want to make 4x4 matrix and cout columns from top to bottom. The problem is I do not know how to make 4x4 matrix that will end up making this task a little bit easier.

Here is the simple code I made:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    char word[16][16] = {"s", "a", "o","r",
                         "e", "e", "c", "e",
                         "s", "s", "i", "n", 
                         "n", "t", "f", "i"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        {
            cout << word[j][i];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
saoreecessinntfi
```

I want it to look like this:

```
sesnaestocifreni
```

As you can see from the matrix I want it to cout like from top to the bottom in every row or column (please sorry for my bad knowledge about matrix)

Also someone told me I need to check the numbers of columns and rows and if they are the same then I can cout them. How to do that all?

Comment: `char word[16][16]` is a 16x16 array. Your 16 elements basically fill the first row of that.

Comment: @Botje But when I write [4][4] it it says "too many initializers for char[4][4]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You may use string to make array easier.
2. It's better to put some leeway in the arrangement. But 16*16 is too big.
3. In order to output the 4*4 range, both i and j must be repeated from 0 to 4.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    char word[5][5] = {"saor", "eece", "ssin", "ntfi"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cout << word[j][i];
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```